# How deploy Flask application on Webfaction?

Tags: python, flask

Anybody know how to deploy a simple Flask application on Webfaction?
I know Webfaction support mod_wsgi and I read the guide on the Flask site but still I can't make my app working. Anybody have a working configuration?

**UPDATE** to answer a comment by Graham Dumpleton.

I get a 500 Internal server error. Apache does not show any error in the logs. The WSGI script is executed and seems to create the application correctly, but I keep getting a 500 error.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: Try turning on debug in Flask. I forget how to do this so you may want to ask on #pocco irc channel. If you use mod_wsgi daemon mode with a single process you could also turn on the Flask debugger.

Comment: did you ever get this working? Did JoshFinnie's answer work for you?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got it working with the following procedure:

- create and app named 'myapp' of type mod_wsgi 3.3/Python 2.7. Webfaction will create the following folders:

  ```
  myapp
       |- apache2
       |- htdocs
  ```
- Webfaction will also automatically create a simple script `index.py` in your `htdocs` directory. Check if the sample script work visiting the root of your newly created application (to do thin on Webfaction you need to "mount" the app on a website). If it's all OK modify the script deleting the content and adding:

  ```
  from myapp import app as application
  ```
- In `apache2/conf/httpd.conf` add the follwing lines:

  ```
  WSGIPythonPath /home/username/webapps/myapp/htdocs/
  #If you do not specify the next directive the app *will* work but you will
  #see index.py in the path of all subdir
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/webapps/myapp/htdocs/index.py


  <Directory /home/username/webapps/myapp/htdocs>
      AddHandler wsgi-script .py
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteBase /
      WSGIScriptReloading On
  </Directory>
  ```
- Restart apache2

Comment: note that myapp.py must be in the python module search path. You can simply do that by adding the following code to your index.py (if myapp.py is stored next to index.py):

`import sys
sys.path.append('/home/<yourusername>/webapps/<yourappname>/htdocs')`

Comment: Actually, without tweaking `sys.path`, I got 500 internal error which was caused by a Python ImportError, which was indicated by the Apache log file in `/home/<your-username>/logs/user/error_<appnname>.log`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a "Custom app (listening on port)" application.  Make a note of the port that is assigned.  Then in your Flask code, you need to put hardcode the port:

```
if __name__ == __main__:
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0' port=XXXXXXX)
```

Where you substitute XXXXXXX with the port that is randomly assigned to your custom app.

Hope that helps.

**EDIT:**

Please use [Raben's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264592/33194), this way should not to be used in Production.

Comment: Using app.run isn't recommended for production. It's easy and will get the job done quickly, but when your project matures, you should switch to something like mod_wsgi.

Comment: Step 2: Through control panel "Add website" pointing to this app.

Comment: Agree with Joe, this is bad for production. app.run() should be used only for development.